# Issues with scanf() and accepting user input

Tags: c, scanf, user-input

I am trying to take in user input with spaces and store it in an array of characters.
After, I want to take in a single character value and store it as a char.
However, when I run my code, the prompt for the character gets ignored and a space is populated instead. How can I take in an array of chars and still be allowed to prompt for a single character after?

```
void main()
{
    char userIn[30];
    char findChar;


    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", userIn);

    printf("Please enter a character to search for: ");
    scanf("%c", &findChar);

    //this was put here to see why my single char wasnt working in a function I had
    printf("%c", findChar);

}
```

Comment: "Issues with scanf" is practically a truism:  http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Is that so? I am barely coming to C from java  so this is a new phenomenon to me.

Comment: Reminder that `scanf` DOES return a valuable result to help indicate the number of items successfully scanned. You could alleviate some of these issues by actually checking that result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Comment: TLDR from the suggested duplicate: Add a space before the `%c` format in `scanf` to skip the leftover newline in the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%c", &findChar);` reads the next character pending in the input stream. This character will be the newline entered by the user that stopped the previous conversion, so `findChar` will be set to the value `'\n'`, without waiting for any user input and `printf` will output this newline without any other visible effect.

Modify the call as `scanf(" %c", &findChar)` to ignore pending white space and get the next character from the user, or more reliably write a loop to read the read and ignore of the input line.

Note also that `scanf("%[^\n]s", userIn);` is incorrect:

- `scanf()` may store bytes beyond the end of `userIn` if the user types more than 29 bytes of input.
- the `s` after the `]` is a bug, the conversion format for character classes is not a variation of the `%s` conversion.

Other problems:

- `void` is not a proper type for the return value of the `main()` function.
- the `<stdio.h>` header is required for this code.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char userIn[30];
    int c;
    char findChar;
    int i, found;

    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    if (scanf("%29[^\n]", userIn) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input failure\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* read and ignore the rest of input line */
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;

    printf("Please enter a character to search for: ");
    if (scanf("%c", &findChar) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input failure\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Searching for '%c'\n", findChar);
    found = 0;
    for (i = 0; userIn[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (userIn[i] == findChar) {
            found++;
            printf("found '%c' at offset %d\n", c, i);
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        printf("character '%c' not found\n", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this makes it impossible for the user to enter whitespace as a search character.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: indeed `scanf(" %c", &findChar)` would not allow for searching for whitespace, but the code I posted uses the other approach: reading and discarding the rest of the first input line and scanning for a single byte with  `scanf(" %c", &findChar)`, which is equivalent to `findChar = getchar()` except for the handling of end of file and input errors.

Comment: Ah, yes, well done.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%[^\n]s", userIn);` is a bit weird.  The `s` is guaranteed not to match, since that character will always be `\n`.  Also, you should use a width modifier to avoid a buffer overflow.  Use `scanf("%29[^\n]", userIn);`  That alone will not solve the problem, since the next scanf is going to consume the newline.  There are a few options. You could consume the newline in the first scanf with:

```
scanf("%29[^\n]%*c", userIn);
```

or discard all whitespace in the next call with

```
scanf(" %c", &findChar);
```

The behavior will differ on lines of input that exceed 29 characters in length or when the user attempts to assign whitespace to `findChar`, so which solution you use will depend on how you want to handle those situations.

Comment: So when you say consume the new line in the first scanF, is that storing the new line in my char array??

Comment: @DavidHernandez No.  The `*` in `%*c` tells scanf to discard the character.

Comment: I see, that's a real nifty tool, thank you for the knowledge.

Comment: @DavidHernandez: Note however that if the user typed more than 29 characters, the `%*c` conversion will just read and ignore the next character, not the newline.

Comment: `scanf("%29[^\n]%*c", userIn);` fails to read any input if input was `"\n"`, leaving `"\n"` in `stdin` and `userIn` unwritten.